# bltoolkit sql query set explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, bltoolkit

Is there any way how to get a SQL query result from a bltoolkit? I need to set the query explicitly..

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The DbManager class contains some appropriate methods: ExecuteList, ExecuteReader, ExecuteObject, ExecuteDataTable, SetSpCommand, etc. See there: http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.Data.ashx

Sample:

```
[MapField("PersonID", "ID")]
public class Person
{
    public int    ID;

    public string LastName;
    public string FirstName;
    public string MiddleName;
    public Gender Gender;
}

IList<Person> GetPersonListSqlText()
{
    using (DbManager db = new DbManager())
    {
        return db
            .SetCommand("SELECT * FROM Person")
            .ExecuteList<Person>();
    }
}
```